# Cancel observable with take or takeUntil

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using rxjs in an Angular app and I want to cancel an observable after it emited a certain amount of items OR an ngUnsubscribe happens.

So this would be

```
private startTimeout() {
    this.timeout$ = Observable.timer(1, 1000)
      .map(x => this.refresh / 1000 - x)
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe);
  }
```

or this

```
private startTimeout() {
    this.timeout$ = Observable.timer(1, 1000)
      .map(x => this.refresh / 1000 - x)
      .take(this.refresh / 1000)
  }
```

How can I mix both? I tried chaining take and takeUntil but it does not work...

Comment: It doesn't work how?

Comment: I guess `this.refresh / 1000` returns a double that is never equal to the number of items you want (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/take.ts#L78). So you should use `Math.round()` for example like this: `.take(Math.round(this.refresh / 1000))`

Comment: take() alone works fine; when I use both of them and send the unsubscribe, it does not terminate it

Comment: It does work for me: http://jsbin.com/quvoyoz/3/edit?js,console

Comment: You're right, @martin, I was sending both a .next and .complete from my Subject and I think that was the problem. As soon as I removed the .complete() it all worked fine. Thanks!